# Check if textareas is not empty

Tags: jquery

I use jquery 1.3.2. Following code works to check if textarea IS empty and also detects pasted text into textarea, which is good. (I found it on forums, do not understand how it works entirely)

```
!$.trim($('#comment').val())
```

I want to check if a textarea with id is NOT empty. How do I write the code, with detecting of paste in mind? Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read about the [logical 'NOT' (`!`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29). Incidentally, if you 'do not understand how it works' try reading the jQuery documentation: [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: And to those 'answering' (so far) note that the OP's code (insofar as it could possibly be considered "the OP's code") demonstrates a requirement to *not* consider white-space as a valid input.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at understanding the code at all? Please, you'd help yourself a great deal if you could do so. Now, that said: how does the above code *fail* to meet your needs? When, or on what event, does it run? Have you, or can you, make an attempt at a solution yourself? If you have made an attempt, can you explain where they went wrong, and post your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#comment').val()` is the value of `#comment` element

use `!=` to mean **different**

**Example:**

if the value is different of 'ball'

```
if ($('#comment').val() != 'ball') {
    //do something
}
```

if the value is different of 'cat'

```
if ($('#comment').val() != 'cat') {
    //do something
}
```

if the value is different of EMPTY

```
if ($('#comment').val() != '') {
    //do something
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfwxY/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (!$("#your-textarea-id").val()){
      // not empty
} else {
      // empty
}
```